# Click "Exit" button through our Application It need to go Phones's Home page & remove SharedPreferences also

Tags: android

My question is when I click the "Exit" button through our application It need to go to Phones's Home screen.I have Tried like this

```
  public void onExitAction(View botton){
          // finish();
          // super.finish();
           // System.runFinalizersOnExit(true)

            //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

     System.exit(0);

}
```

Not working.

When I put `finish()` its closing that particular activity & its go to previous screen.

seconds one is When we exit the system need to remove `SharedPreferences` also?

Please help me on this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public void onExitAction(View botton){       
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
    finish();       
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working fine. But one problem is there! After click application its go to last opened place.I strore the login user info in the `SharedPreferences` . how we can rempve when we exit the app?

Comment: can you clarify it.I didn't understand

Comment: "Exit" is ok now. Now I want this , After Exit app, It go to home. Then Again I click my app (select/lounge  my app), I should go to My app login Screen.I saved login info part in`SharedPreferences`. When The user click Exit, That time need to remove saved 'SharedPreferences' info also....

Comment: If you need to clear saved info then use prefEditor.clear() after calling finish();

Answer (score 0):

use

```
    moveTaskToBack(true);
```

for your exit button. Though it will not kill the application.it will just move the application to background and displays the Home screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 logbackbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
        //      MyTestglobe.class);
        //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), firstActivity.class);
myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```